# Loop through JSON keys and values and same time replacing specify matched value in golang

Tags: json, loops, go, interface

Is there any way to loop all over keys and values of json and thereby confirming and replacing a specific value by matched path or matched compared key or value and simultaneously creating a new interface of out of the json after being confirmed with the key new value in Golang.

This an example i saw that loops through all values https://play.golang.org/p/xtiT2iGocBg but i have no idea of replacing values by matched path or value

Comment: It's always helpful to post about what you tried.

Comment: Yes, But that is what i'm trying since without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! I completed the full specification of what i were looking for!!

https://play.golang.org/p/eN4-FjaQS97

```
   package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
        {
        "iw":{"Ie":{"Itye":{"e":"eIe"}}},
"InnerJSON2":"NoneValue",
    "outterJSON":{
        "innerJSON1":{
            "value1":10,
            "value2":22
            ,
            "InnerInnerArray": [ "test1" , "test2"],
            "InnerInnerJSONArray": [ {"fld1" : "val1"} , {"fld2" : "val2"} ]
            },
            "InnerJSON2":"NoneValue"
        }
    }
    `)

    f := map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    verifyJSON(f)
    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(f, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}

func verifyJSON(bv interface{}) {

    var dumpJSON func(v interface{}, kn string)

    dumpJSON = func(v interface{}, kn string) {
        iterMap := func(x map[string]interface{}, root string) {

            var knf string
            if root == "root" {
                knf = "%v/%v"
            } else {
                knf = "%v/%v"
            }
            for k, v := range x {

                switch vv := v.(type) {

                case map[string]interface{}:

                    fmt.Printf("%s => (map[string]interface{}) ...\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))

                case []interface{}:
                    fmt.Printf("%s => ([]interface{}) ...\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
                default:
                    fmt.Printf("%s => %v\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k), vv)
                    x[k] = "rgk"
                }
                dumpJSON(v, fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
            }
        }

        iterSlice := func(x []interface{}, root string) {
            var knf string
            if root == "root" {
                knf = "%v/%v"

            } else {
                knf = "%v/%v"
            }
            for k, v := range x {

                switch vv := v.(type) {

                case map[string]interface{}:

                    fmt.Printf("%s => (map[string]interface{}) ...\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))

                case []interface{}:
                    fmt.Printf("%s => ([]interface{}) ...\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
                default:

                    fmt.Printf("%s => %v\n", fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k), vv)

                    x[k] = "rg"
                }

                dumpJSON(v, fmt.Sprintf(knf, root, k))
            }
        }

        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            iterMap(vv, kn)
        case []interface{}:
            iterSlice(vv, kn)
        default:

        }
    }
    dumpJSON(bv, "root")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally succeeded in getting keys/values and can same time replace any values or keys now, but the last step i'm battling now is how can i get the `aMap[key]` and `anArray[i]` paths respectively of all values. E.g   `"test2": "TEST EACH REPLACE "` has a path of `outterJSON.innerJSON1.nnerInnerArray.1.test2` but can be in any format.

https://play.golang.org/p/TNkonE8AkoJ

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"   
)
 var co=""
func main() {
    //Creating the maps for JSON
    m := map[string]interface{}{}

    //Parsing/Unmarshalling JSON encoding/json
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    parseMap(m)

    fmt.Println(co)

    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(m,"", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}

func parseMap(aMap map[string]interface{}) {
    for key, val := range aMap {
        switch concreteVal := val.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:

        co += key+"."
            fmt.Println(key+"NwHN")
            parseMap(val.(map[string]interface{}))

        case []interface{}:
        co += key+"."
            fmt.Println(key+"NHN")
            parseArray(val.([]interface{}))

        default:

        fmt.Println("OOOOO")
        aMap[key]="TEST EACH REPLACE "
            fmt.Println(key, "v:", concreteVal)

        }
    }
}

func parseArray(anArray []interface{}) {
    for i, val := range anArray {
        switch concreteVal := val.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:

            fmt.Println("Indexr:", i)
            parseMap(val.(map[string]interface{}))

        case []interface{}:

            fmt.Println("Indexb:", i)
            parseArray(val.([]interface{}))


        default:
        anArray[i]= "TEST EACH REPLACE ARR"
            fmt.Println("Index", i, ":", concreteVal)

        }
    }
}

const input = `
{
"ouj":"ou",
    "outterJSON":{
        "innerJSON1":{
            "value1":10,
            "value2":22
            ,
            "InnerInnerArray": [ "test1" , {"test2":"valtest2"}],
            "InnerInnerJSONArray": [ {"fld1" : "val1"} , {"fld2" : "val2"} ]
            },
            "InnerJSON2":"NoneValue"
        }
    }
    `
```